# DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a df dataframe which contains my browser history. This is how the data looks: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOgwa.png) [rest of the columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moZUl.png)
I then created a df_new DataFrameGroupBy object to create a group of df based on 'hour' and 'dt'.
Then I used the reset_index function on df_new but it is giving me the error: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'. I have tried to find a solution but I am stumped. Please help me solve it, thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['hour','dt'])
df_new = df_new.reset_index(name="count")
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to use the df_new to create a heatmap with the date in the x axis, hour in the y, and the counts being represented in the map.

Comment: Please concretely describe your expected output. I'm voting to close since this hasn't been made clear.

Comment: Can you describe what is not clear?

Comment: If you used `groupby` and then reset the index without any operation your output dataframe would be identical to your input dataframe. You need to perform an operation in between, e.g. `count()` to get the number of entries per `['hour', 'dt']`: `df_new = df.groupby(['hour','dt']).count().reset_index()`